# Android Databinding width with ternary using dp in XML

Tags: android, android-layout, android-databinding

I know I can use @dimen/something... but was wondering why this does not work and how to get it to work.  Will help me understand the black box of databinding parser.

In my XML for a lineralayout element:

```
android:layout_width="@{DataBoundData.dis.equals(IN_PROGRESS) ? 60dp : 
     (DataBoundData.dis.equals(POSTED) ? 60dp : 0dp)}"
```

It shows an error on the 'p' in 60dp.  I have tried 60d\p `60dp` and a few others and nothing works

Comment: Forget the ternary for the moment. Does `android:layout_width="@{60dp}"` work?

Comment: @{60dp} and @{'60dp'} do not work

Comment: Hence, the problem isn't the ternary. My assumption is that the expression language simply does not handle dimension constants.

Comment: yeah but you can add @dimen/somedimension, which is why I want to understand what is going on with the databinding parser.

Comment: "you can add @dimen/somedimension" -- that is not a dimension constant. You might consider filing a feature request to have the data binding expression language support dimension constants.

Comment: android:layout_width="@{DataBoundData.dis.equals(IN_PROGRESS) ? @dimen/show_button : @dimen/do_not_show_button}" this doesn't work either yet this is what others are doing...

Comment: What are your exact symptoms? "doesn't work" does not give anyone much to go on.

Comment: @CommonsWare Why is it you take the time to answer or even comment on peoples questions yet you never seem to up vote?.  I know you have a huge rep here but you got the 679K by people up voting your questions or answers.  Some day it would be nice to get an up vote from you.  This is the 4th time you have commented or answered yet no up vote...just saying.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To answer the question of why `android:layout_width="@{60dp}"` doesn't work, it is because data binding doesn't understand the concept of 'dp'.

You've already created some kind of BindingAdapter for the attribute or it wouldn't work at all, because `layout_width` isn't supported by default. Maybe you have something like this:

```
@BindingAdapter("android:layout_width")
public static void setLayoutWidth(View view, float width) {
    LayoutParams layoutParams = view.getLayoutParams();
    layoutParams.width = (int)width;
    view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
}
```

There is no indication on the BindingAdapter what the `float width` is. It has no type, so there is no way to transfer that knowledge to the constants in the data binding system. It is the same reason you must use

```
android:visibility="@{View.INVISIBLE}"
```

instead of

```
android:visibility="@{invisible}"
```

There is no java constant `invisible` in the context of setting the int value on `setVisibility()`

You *can* pass in an integer constant like `60` and it will assign it. Unfortunately, those are pixels for LayoutParams and that changes between devices.

When you use `@dimen/someDimension`, data binding converts the dimension into an float at the time the value is extracted from the resources. That's easy to understand because `Resources.getDimension()` returns a `float`. Likewise, `Resources.getColor()` returns an integer, so every time you pass a color resource, you're passing an integer around.

Hope that helps.

Comment: So if I were to use a float instead the it would understand?  By the way, well put ... your explanation, glad you took the time to teach me something new!

Comment: Yes, it would work, but it would be in terms of pixels and not dp. Good for prototyping, maybe, but not great for a real application.